# How to show real SQL of specific line in Grails(hibernate)?

Tags: hibernate, grails

I just want to see the specific SQL being called when I execute this one method. Is there a way to do this is grails? I am aware I could do this:

```
log4j = {

    // Enable Hibernate SQL logging with param values
    trace 'org.hibernate.type'
    debug 'org.hibernate.SQL'
    //the rest of your logging config
    // ...
    }
```

or this:

```
datasource {
...
logSql = true
}
```

The code above is very messy because **it logs everything** and I have a lot of jobs in the background and I can see all of it. I just want to see a **specific** one. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: No, there is no way to target a specific SQL call for logging. It's either everything, or nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question. No, there is no way to target a specific SQL call for logging. It's either everything or nothing.

Comment: Thanks for informing me. I have decided to turn off all background jobs so that it becomes easier to find the specific sql statement I'm looking for.